# kubernetes pod exit 137 and resource limit is not set

Tags: linux, mysql, docker, kubernetes

## error

Hey, All friends, my pod is exit with code 137 when i connect mysql in this pod.

## error message

```
command terminated with non-zero exit code: Error executing in Docker Container: 137
```

## environment

- kubernetes: 1.14.1
- docker: 18.0.9
- mysql: 5.7
- install method: helm

## What

picture0[image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/29370146/57617615-ccf95980-75b3-11e9-80eb-f55da4c09427.png)
This is my pod, it's running, enn~ very good!
So i use nextcloud in web, and external mysql is this pod. But pod don't work, and tell me the message!
picture1[image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/29370146/57617738-1d70b700-75b4-11e9-8e11-f61599c47c9d.png)

## Hope

I wanna know Why it don't work, And i should do what to solve it.

## note

In my logic machine, not vm, it work well!
And my pod resource is not set limit!
And it's important it worker normally in my local(not kubernetes).